# Change Zend Framework 2 default template resolver behavior

Tags: php, view, namespaces, zend-framework2

I've just started looking into Zend framework 2 .One thing that I can’t seem to figure out is how to change the behavior of the framework when its deciding what view template to use when i’m not passing it in the viewmodel.

When looking for the answer myself I found the following, which states that Zend resolves view templates using the pathing below:

`{normalized-module-name}/{normalized-controller-name}/{normalized-action-name}`

(Source: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Question-regarding-template-path-stack-tp4660952p4660959.html)

Now I’m looking to edit or remove the normalized-module-name segment. All the view files stay in my module/views folder. The reason I want to change this is because I’m using sub namespaces as my module name, resulting in the first segment of the namespace as the normalized module name (which is not specific enough for me).

To give you an example, the module `Foo\Bar` will result in an example view being rendered from:

`/modules/Foo/Bar/view/foo/test/index.phtml`.

I would like to change that default behavior to:

`/modules/Foo/Bar/view/bar/test/index.phtml`

Comment: not sure i get you but this is how i set my template $view->setTemplate('path');

Comment: Hey @dixromos98, your suggested answer is indeed correct if you would like to tell ZF2 manually that it needs to use a specific view. I’m just curious if there is any way to change the behavior of ZF2 when not setting the template.

Comment: Thank you all for answering my question! I left the code concerned this question at the office, so i'll get back to you on Monday as soon as possible to mark the correct answer as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem and here's my solution.

Default template injector is attached to an event manager of the current controller with priority -90, and it resolves a template name only if a view model is not provided with one. 
Knowing this, you can create your own template injector with a required logic and attach it to the event manager with the higher priority.

Please see the code below:

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $event)
{
    $eventManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $eventManager->getSharedManager()
        ->attach(
            'Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface',
            MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,
            new TemplateInjector(),
            -80 // you can put here any negative number higher -90
        );
}
```

Your template injector which resolves template paths instead of the default one.

```
class TemplateInjector 
{
    public function __invoke(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $model = $event->getResult();

        if (!$model instanceof ViewModel)
        {
            return;
        }

        $controller = $event->getTarget();


        if ($model->getTemplate())
        {
            return ;
        }

        if (!is_object($controller))
        {
            return;
        }

        $namespace = explode('\\', ltrim(get_class($controller), '\\'));

        $controllerClass = array_pop($namespace);
        array_pop($namespace); //taking out the folder with controllers
        array_shift($namespace); //taking out the company namespace

        $moduleName = implode('/', $namespace);

        $controller = substr($controllerClass, 0, strlen($controllerClass) - strlen('Controller'));
        $action = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action');
        $model->setTemplate(strtolower($moduleName.'/'.$controller.'/'.$action));
    }
}
```

Here's the link from my blog where I wrote about it in more details: http://blog.igorvorobiov.com/2014/10/18/creating-a-custom-template-injector-to-deal-with-sub-namespaces-in-zend-framework-2/

Comment: The answer of Next Developer was the most suitable for me at this moment because of the code examples provided. Iku practically said the same but since I am pretty new to Zend it was a bit harder to understand. Both Iku and Exlord had valid points by telling me I should probably define the template manually, optimizing the performance. And I also liked the answer of Xerkus because it was the most “clean” solution of getting things done. Since I don’t have enough reputation to upvote all of you, I’m marking Next Developer’s answer as the solved one. But thank you all for participating.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with zf 2.3 you can use extra config parameter `view_manager['controller_map']` to enable different template name resolving.

Look at this PR for more info: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/5670

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'controller_map' => array(
        'Foo\Bar' => true,
    ),
);
```

Will result in controller FQCN starting with 'Foo\Bar' to be resolved following those rules:

1. strip \Controller\ namespace
2. strip trailing Controller in classname
3. inflect CamelCase to dash
4. replace namespace separator with slash

Eg: `Foo\Bar\Controller\Baz\TestController` -> `foo/bar/baz/test/actionname`

**Update:**

Starting with zend-mvc v3.0 this is default behavior

Answer (score 0):

Right template to ViewModel is injected in MVC event 'dispatch' (defined in [ViewManager](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/ViewManager.php#L141)) by `Zend\Mvc\View\Http\InjectTemplateListener` with priority -90

You'll have to create custom InjectTemplateListener and register it with higher priority to same event.

But I'd recommend to set template in every action by hand, because of performance - see http://samminds.com/2012/11/zf2-performance-quicktipp-1-viewmodels/

Answer (score 0):

template name resolving is a heavy process(on system resources), and all the articles about ZF2 performance says that you should provide the template name manually to increase performance.

so don't waste time finding a way to do something that you will end up doing manually :D

Answer (score 0):

In order to improve Next Developer answer, I write the following code in TemplateInjector.php:

```
class TemplateInjector
{

    public function __invoke(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $model = $event->getResult();

        if (!$model instanceof ViewModel) {
            return;
        }

        if ($model->getTemplate()) {
            return;
        }

        $controller = $event->getTarget();

        if (!is_object($controller)) {
            return;
        }

        $splitNamespace = preg_split('/[\\\]+/', ltrim(get_class($controller), '\\'));
        $moduleName = $splitNamespace[1];
        $controller = $splitNamespace[0];
        $action = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action');
        $model->setTemplate(strtolower($moduleName . '/' . $controller . '/' . $action));
    }
}
```

I've changed the way to build the Template path. Using regexp is faster than using array methods.